How to resolve nginx SSL error
I'm running nginx on a Raspberry PI which has reserved & allocated LAN address of 192.168.2.10 on router 192.168.2.1. When I put http://192.168.2.10 into Firefox, I get SSL handshake Failure in /var/log/nginx/error.log:
2024/10/21 16:06:17 [crit] 29586#29586: *370 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 51.159.14.99, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2024/10/21 16:06:20 [crit] 29586#29586: *391 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 51.159.111.112, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2024/10/21 16:22:10 [crit] 29586#29586: *415 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 34.96.46.130, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2024/10/21 16:24:05 [crit] 30283#30283: *12 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 34.96.46.24, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Any ideas please?
Firefox is version 128.3.1ESR.
nginx.conf below and my index.html is in:
/var/www/index.html
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}


Your question doesn't make much sense. If you're testing in your own LAN you wouldn't see errors with different public internet IP-addresses as the result of your own troubleshooting. Note that additionally without the actual nginx configuration it is hard to diagnose if you misconfigured your webserver, or if instead the problem is not with your webserver but rather with the clients, the site visitors (or your own outdated Firefox), that use out-dated encryption ciphers and algorithms for example. For example you can't support legacy clients when you only allow TLS 1.3 from the server.

I've put more info in the original post.

Looks more like you have forwarded the server port 443 on your internet router, making your ngix available on the internet and the common port scanners and attackers have already found it.

@Robert What is the best way to correct this?

Don't expose you server to the internet (-> use VPN to your home net) or if you want t keep it accessible from Internet you have to accept that other will try to access it and cause error in the log.

I previously used the Pi successfully running nginx, VPN (used by me when away from home) and AdGuard. I put the Pi away due to domestic circumstances. I've now brought the OS etc up to date using apt. As well as getting the nginx error , I'm not able to access my webpages on other devices e.g. phone). Does this mean that someone has hacked the Pi? If so, how do I correct it?

Normally you'd expect more configuration settings in the included snippets include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; and include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* and customary is, as far as I know,  that nginx TLS settings are in the server{}  blocks for each site, often seen in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* rather than in the http{} bock - What I can see is that you set ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 ... which shouldn't be needed unless you KNOW you need to support legacy clients (i.e. IE on Win XP and/or Win Vista) because TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1 has been deprecated in January 2020 by modern browsers

The nginx.conf was installed as the default when nginx was installed. Please explain why nginx igives the SSL Handshake error and what I need to do to correct it.

where is the part that you configure the SSL cert? if you want just http, remove everything that have SSL in the command. also, make sure that your browser does not doing HTTP to HTTPS redirection automatically. I believe Chrome is doing that now by default
